# Remove unwanted characters from a List using C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, trim

I have a Multi-Line text box that I can paste a list of any text items into, like this:

```
555-555-1212
I want's a lemon's.
google.com
1&1 Hosting
```

I also have a text box next to it that I can add comma separated strings that I want removed from all items in my list, like this:

```
-,$,!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,),.com,.net,.org
```

I am trying to figure out how to scrub each of these strings(or whatever other strings I put in that second text box) from each of the strings in my textbox List.

Any ideas?  I know how to get the List into a List-string, but not sure how to scrub that string.

This is what I have so far...but I am getting red squigglies:

```
List<string> removeChars = new List<string>(textBox6.Text.Split(','));                 
for (int i = 0; i < sortBox1.Count; i++)
{
    sortBox1[i] = Regex.Replace(sortBox1[i], removeChars, "").Trim();
}
```

Comment: I figured out how to get the multiline textbox into a list, and the scrubbed strings into a list, but not sure how to scrub.

Comment: a simple way to solve your problem will be using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx
C# has ready soultions for nearly any basic problem. you should take time to read a C# book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) on every string in the unwanted-list for every line in `Textbox.Lines`.

```
string[] replaceStrings = txtUnwanted.Text.Split(',');
List<string> lines = new List<string>(textBox1.Lines);
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
    foreach (string repl in replaceStrings)
        lines[i] = lines[i].Replace(repl, "");
```

Edit: here's a demo: http://ideone.com/JQl79k (without windows controls since ideone doesn't support it)

Comment: Worked perfectly, Tim.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] lines = new string[] { "555-555-1212", "I want's a lemon's.", "google.com", "1&1 Hosting" };
    string[] removables = textBox1.Text.Split(',');
    string[] newLine = new string[lines.Count()];

    int i = 0;
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        newLine[i] = line;
        foreach (string rem in removables)
        {
            while(newLine[i].Contains(rem))
                newLine[i] = newLine[i].Remove(newLine[i].IndexOf(rem), rem.Length);
        }
        MessageBox.Show(newLine[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

result:

**5555551212

 I wants a lemons

 googlecom

 1&1 Hosting**